# How to conect USB modem dongle to tablet AOC Breeze

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, root-access, apn, usb-modem

I have a tablet AOC Breeze model MW0712 with Android 4.1.1.

I want to connect with USB modem dongle Huawei E303C in order to have internet connection, but with no success results.

I try with this [link](http://www.ingenieroinformatico.org/2013/01/modem-3g-usb-en-tablet-con-sistema.html) (in spanish, because I'm peruvian and the APN settings is for my ISP), but I can't save any APN settings as I explain [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63479/apn-doesnt-save-in-tablet-aoc-breeze).

I try with [this widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.draisberghof.pppwidget&hl=es_419), but always give me a "No driver found" message.

Then I try with [this tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2172914) (rooting the tablet) and supporting me with [this one](http://www.elandroidelibre.com/2013/06/conecta-cualquier-modem-usb-a-cualquier-tablet-android-root.html) (in spanish) that I think is better explained (but in both tutorials doesn't says that you need the BusyBox app installed). But I could also not connect.

Finally I try with [this APP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=umts.manager.jk&hl=es_419), but the connection is very unstable.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a long time trying to UMTS Manager and XDA forum script, but I realized that when the app was active, the script runs fine (the ping give a good request), then I thought the script needed more time to connect so I make a little modifications to the file "system/etc/ppp/peers/conf-chat" replacing all the "TIMEOUT 3" by "TIMEOUT 0". Then in the GScript Mod app I change in the inet-ON script the sleeps in the for statement (that was setting in 3) for sleep by 5.

When I make these little modifications the tablet connects and surf in the internet like a charm!

Please, sorry for my english and for answer my own question in this way but I think could be another guy with the same problem.